# Php/MySQL: time isn't matching properly with current time

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I created a program where u type in the date and time and then on clicking submit, it tells you whether the typed in date and time are same as the current date and time.. the problem i am having with the time part is that no matter what time i put in, it says "same time" idk why. The date one is working fine but the time one isn't.

```
<?php
session_start();
$EntryError=$EntryTimeError="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $entrydate = $EntryTime = "";
    $errorOccured = false;

    if (isset($_POST['tsmdate'])){
        $entrydate = trim($_POST['tsmdate']);
        if (strlen($entrydate) == 0){
            $EntryError = "date is missing";
            $errorOccured = true;
        }
      else{
        $presentDate=date('Y-m-d');
           if(strtotime($entrydate) == strtotime($presentDate))
            {
              echo "same date";

           }
          else{
             echo "different date";
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $EntryError = "date is missing";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tsmTime'])){
            $EntryTime = trim($_POST['tsmTime']);
            if (strlen($EntryTime) == 0){
                $EntryTimeError = "time is missing";
                $errorOccured = true;
            }

        else{
            $EntryTimeError = "time is missing";
        $presentTime= date('h:i A', strtotime($EntryTime));
        if(strtotime($EntryTime) == strtotime($presentTime))
            {
              echo "same time";

           }
          else{
             echo "different time";
            }
        }
    }
     else{
        $EntrytError = "time is missing";
    }
}
?>
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="dates" id="dates" method="POST" action="">
<table cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <h1> select dates </h1>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="right">
                    <label for="tsmdate">Entry date </label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="date" name="tsmdate" id="tsmdate" required="required">
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td width="30%" align="right">
                    <label for="tsmTime">Entry time</label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="time" name="tsmTime" id="tsmTime" required="required">
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="dates">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$presentTime` is always the same as the `$EntryTime`. This is because you use the entry time in the date function.

Change

```
$presentTime= date('h:i A', strtotime($EntryTime));
```

to

```
$presentTime= date('h:i A');
```

Comment: yea i figured that out thanks however, there is one problem, the time they show me isn't the present time. for example, its 12:27 am here and the date is 5th, it is showing me 4th,1:27 am. I even tried changing the timezone to my country but didnt work

Comment: So you want the 24h format? Than you should use H instead of h. You can add the current date to the EntryTime to fix the date problem.